# How can BitLocker be configured to not require additional authentication if Secure Boot is disabled

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, bitlocker, secure-boot, tpm

I have a laptop with Windows 10 1703 installed, that I am trying to determine how BitLocker has been configured on.

In the BIOS the laptop has Discrete TPM selected but also has the option of Intel PTT. Secure boot is disabled in the BIOS though and Windows reports that secure boot is unsupported.

When I boot the laptop I get straight to the log in screen without entering a pin or requiring a USB key.

Manage BitLocker in Windows reports that BitLocker is on for C:

My understanding, based mostly on [this](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2020/05/unlocking-bitlocker-can-you-break-that-password/) article from Elcomsoft, was that once you are at the login screen the drive is decrypted, and this only happens without being prompted for additional authentication when BitLocker is TPM only protected, and that this relies on secure boot, which in this case is disabled.

Unfortunately I only have a standard user so cannot check certain things such as if any group policy has been used to configure BitLocker.  That being said I don't know what Group Policy would allow this configuration.

**Update:**
I have been able to get someone with administrative access to provide the output of `manage-bde c: -protectors -get`.

The protectors returned were `Numerical Password` with an `ID` and `Password`, followed by `TPM` which included an `ID` and listed the `PCR Validation Profile` as `0, 2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11`

Comment: BitLocker doesn't strictly require Secure Boot for this – it's certainly preferred to have (for kernel/bootloader upgrade reasons) but there's a fallback TPM-only mechanism as well. I'll check later for where the log locations are. Meanwhile please add the output of `manage-bde c: -protectors -get` in your post (minus the recovery password of course).

Comment: If you have any links that would be greatly appreciated.  Microsoft documentation can be very detailed but not the easiest to navigate!

Comment: @Jon - Please provide the required information necessary to answer your question.  The command suggested might require Administrator permissions but without the output of the command your question cannot be answered

Comment: @Ramhound unfortunately that command does require admin priveleges so I cannot run it.  I would very much like to understand how it can be configured and how BitLockers keys are protected if there is any documentation even if I cannot confirm it in this instance. The link I included has a very good overview but doesn't seem to cover this scenario nor do any of the other similar questions on this site.

Comment: @Jon - In order to answer your question we must understand how BitLocker is configured.  Have somebody with the ability to run the command provide you the information so you can provide it to us.  Secure Boot is not required for BitLocker to use TPM to secure the BitLocker key.  Furthermore, an example of this, is the fact Windows 7 supported BitLocker but does not support Secure Boot.

Comment: @Ramhound I will try and get that information.  In the meantime do you have any details on configuring BitLocker on Windows 10 with a TPM without Secure boot as this is what I could not find and the reason for the question.

Comment: @user1686 I have updated the question with the output of the command.  I hope that is sufficient information without including the ID's and passwords as I wasn't entirely sure what should be kept private.

Comment: The long password under "Numerical password" should remain private, most everything else can be made public. Specifically, which PCRs are listed for the TPM?

Comment: @user1686 I have just updated again to list the PCRs.